# Bootstrap change span width based on viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, viewport, html

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/YXwwTP8W

I have a sidebar (span4) and main (span 8)
sidebar has the hidden-phone property on. How do I get main to fill the space (become span 12) on the phone viewport?